# Meus componentes de material não estão sendo reconhecidos na minha Activity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Reinstalei Android Studio no meu computador, fui fazer uma aplicação básica
Só tela de login e um botão para avançar
Mas na activity, ao digitar a id que foi atribuida no xml, o arquivo Kotlin não reconhece nada do que esta lá. Nem botão e nem os textos.

**Arquivo Kotlin**

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnAvancar.setOnClickListener(){

        }
    }
}```

**Arquivo XML** 

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Tela_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/User"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/user_name" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/Senha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/User">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAvancar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Senha"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>'''
````

Comment: Possivelmente está faltando: apply plugin: ‘kotlin-android-extensions’. Porém este plugin  foi deprecado para o kotlin 1.4,  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42121.

Answer (score -1):

Você só precisa adicionar a seguinte linha no seu método `onCreate()`:

```kotlin
val bt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAvancar)
```

Assim você faz uma busca no seu xml pelo identificador do botão e consegue ter acesso a ele a partir da variável `bt`. Seu código ficará assim:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        val bt = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAvancar)

        bt.setOnClickListener(){
            //sua ação de clique aqui
        }
    }
}
```